# postgres creating schema in default 'postgres' database instead of specified database while executing .sql files from .bat file

Tags: sql, postgresql, batch-file

my init.bat file looks as below

init.bat

```
SET PGPASSWORD=youtube123
F:\applications\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql -U postgres -w -f database.sql
F:\applications\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql -U postgres -w -f schema.sql 
pause
```

database.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE "tester"
WITH 
OWNER = "admin"
TEMPLATE = template2
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
TABLESPACE = pg_default
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "tester" TO "admin" WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

schema.sql

```
CREATE SCHEMA "test_schema"
AUTHORIZATION "admin";
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA "test_schema" TO "admin" WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I have created the role **admin** and granted full previlizes.

When running my init.bat file the test_schema need to be created in tester database instead of postgres. But the schema was creating  under postgres database.

What should be the change that i need to do to create schema under a specified database(tester). When running the .sql scripts through batch file.

Thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you must connect to the proper database

```
F:\applications\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql -d tester -U postgres -w -f schema.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

In the application properties if you set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`
Schema in the postgres database won't get created. You can write the schema in the postgres itself.

If you set `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`, Schema will be created automatically.